# Expectation of (1/x)-1 possible transformation involved??

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, transformation, expectation

I'm a bit confused with the first steps in this problem:

> $F(x)=x^4$ for $0<x<1$
>
> a) Find $E[(1/X)-1]$
>
> b) Let $Y=(1/X)-1$. Find the support of $Y$, its pdf and CDF. Name its distribution and its parameters.
>
> c) Compute $E(Y)$ and compare it to the result in part a.
>
> d) Compute the variance of $Y$ (or use know formulae).

So I can tell that the CDF given is a Beta correct? With a pdf of $f(x)=4x^3$. Now to find the expected value of a) is there some sort of transformation involved here? or do I just (integrate $x \cdot ((1/X)-1)$) but that is just an equation so I don't know here I'm lost. Just looking for guidance with this problem that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose that the random variable $X$ has density function $f_X(x)$. Let $Y=g(X)$. Then (for reasonable $g$) we have
$$E(Y)=E(g(X))=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f_X(x)\,dx.$$

For the variance of $Y^2$, one way is to calculate $E(Y^2)$ in basically the same way as you computed $E(Y)$, and use the fact that $\text{Var}(Y)=E(Y^2)-(E(Y))^2$.

For the distribution of $Y$, the support of $X$ is $(0,1)$, so $\frac{1}{X}$ ranges over the interval $(1,\infty)$, and therefore $Y$ ranges over $(0,\infty)$.

To find the distribution of $Y$, you can use a transformation. Or else you can compute $\Pr(Y\le y)$ directly, since for positive $y$ we have $\frac{1}{X}-1\le y$ if and only if $X\ge \frac{1}{1+y}$.

Comment: so we are taking integral of (1/X)−1 * 4x^3 from -infinity to infinity?

Comment: The density function of $X$ is $4x^3$ on $(0,1)$ and $0$ elsewhere. So the integral displayed in the answer comes down to $\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)(4x^3)\,dx$.

Comment: got it. Now the 1/y+1 gets inserted back in the CDF and then you take the derivative, correct?

Comment: I don't understand the question. We multiply through, getting $4x^2-4x^3$, and integrate. The result is $\frac{1}{3}$. Now we have the mean. For the cumulative distributive function of $Y$, we use the probability that $X\ge \frac{1}{1+y}$, which is $1-\frac{1}{(1+y)^4}$, and differentiate.

Comment: ok that makes sense. How do I go about identifying that PDF 4/(y+1)^5 its support seems to be 0 < x < infinity, not a Beta, is it a Pareto?

Comment: It is one of the Pareto (power law) distributions.

Comment: hmmm never heard of those, i'll look it up. So alpha=4 and C=1?

Comment: For some variants of Pareto, please [see this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Pareto_types_I.E2.80.93IV) Your density function is of course right.

Comment: great I really appreciate the direction you gave

Comment: You are welcome.